# @PropertySources - how to use different sources properly?

Tags: java, spring

Lets consider that we have two *properties* files and would like to read some of these properties. Starting from *Spring 4.0* it is possible to do it using annotation ***@PropertySources***. I found that it could be done this way:

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource(name = "first", value = "classpath:first.properties"),
    @PropertySource(name = "second", value = "classpath:second.properties")
})
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public SomeBean someBean {
        //reading from first properties file
        org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource<?> first =
           ((StandardEnvironment) environment).getPropertySources().get("first"));    
        first.getProperty("someProperty");
        //reading from second properties file
        org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource<?> second =
           ((StandardEnvironment) environment).getPropertySources().get("second"));
        second.getProperty("someProperty");
    }
}
```

*Is it a proper way? Do you know a better one?*

Comment: The way you are getting the property seems fine. You could improove it by using constants for property source names. And instead of casting you could autowire an AbstractEnvironment or something like that. You could also use .getPropertySources().iterator() if you'd like.

Comment: Good points, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what could be done more:

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource(name = AppConfig.FIRST, value = "classpath:first.properties"),
    @PropertySource(name = AppConfig.SECOND, value = "classpath:second.properties")
})    
public class AppConfig {

static final String FIRST = "first";
static final String SECOND = "second";

@Autowired
private AbstractEnvironment defaultConfiguration;

@Bean
public SomeBean someBean {
    //reading from first properties file         
    firstConfiguration().getProperty("someProperty");
    //reading from second properties file
    secondConfiguration().getProperty("someProperty");
}

@Bean
public org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource<?> firstConfiguraiton() {
    return defaultConfiguration.getPropertySources().get(FIRST);
}

@Bean
public org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource<?> secondConfiguration() {
    return defaultConfiguration.getPropertySources().get(SECOND);
}
}
```